# Why I can't move img and alink text and my navbar don't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here][1]I tried to much to move the image and link button and tried to make the navbar works on mobile but not very good
I used this code to try to move my image and the link:

```
<td width="500px"><a href="CPU.html"><img src="img/amd.jpeg" style=" top: 10%;" align="centre"></a>
<td width="500px"><a href="CPU.html"><img src="img/amd.jpeg" ></a>
```

and this the bootstrap navbar that don't work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and I tried to resize the link text by this code but doesn't work too :

```
<a href="CPU.html" style=" 
            
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black; "  ><b size="50">CPU</b></a>
```

This was a pity

and I tried to make it as I made it in Nicepage
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcrt5.png

Comment: Whats <td width="500px"> doing there without a closing tag and whats <b size="50">CPU</b>

Comment: Oh! Thanks for remember me that <td> not completed tried to  make two columns have the same size and I forgot it because I was writing a lot of codes @Grumpy